# Python column retains original updated 'NA'; never gets updated with float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series, divide-by-zero

When updating dataframe column, FractionOfVote, my first step was to add a new column, FractionOfVote, with default
NA value. Then parse the dataframe column, Votes, using split.

The following two functions code works fine: 1) add_new_column_fraction(), 2) add_new_column_votes().

```
def add_new_column_fraction(df):
    df['FractionOfVote'] = 'NA'

def add_new_column_votes(df):
    df[['YesVotes','NumVotes']] = df['Votes'].str.split('/',expand=True)[[0,1]]
```

The problem code is found in function calc_fraction_ratio_for_votes()

```
def calc_fraction_ratio_for_votes(df):
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        numerator = row['YesVotes']
        denomerator = row['NumVotes']
        try:
            row['FractionOfVote'] = float(numerator) / float(denomerator)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            row['FractionOfVote'] = 'NaN'
```

This function takes two other dataframe columns, YesVotes, NumVotes, and calculates a new float value for the new
column, FractionOfVote, defined previously in add_new_column_fraction().

The logical error is that column, FractionOfVote, retains the original updated 'NA'; and never received the update from "row['FractionOfVote'] = float(numerator) / float(denomerator)" with either the float value calculation, or the 'NaN' from the "except ZeroDivisionError".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and avoid Python-level loops. First ensure your series are numeric (if necessary):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Yes': [0, 3, 0, 10, 0],
                   'Num': [0, 5, 0, 30, 2]})

num_cols = ['Yes', 'Num']
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Then use division and replace `inf` with `NaN`:

```
print((df['Yes'] / df['Num']).replace(np.inf, np.nan))

0         NaN
1    0.600000
2         NaN
3    0.333333
4    0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks, right on, Python level loops on data.frames appear to operate somewhat irregular, thanks for catching and the commendation to avoid Python loops on data.frame when a data.frame level function is more appropriate to use

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `iterrrows()` in the first place? You can achieve the same results with a vectorized implementation as below:

```
 # Create column and fill all values to NaN by default
 df['FractionOfVote'] = np.nan # import numpy as np if you didn't

 # Populate the valid values with the ratio.
 df.loc[df['NumVotes'].astype(float) > 0, 'FractionOfVote'] = df['YesVotes'] / df['NumVotes']
```

Comment: Why I was using iterrow(), too many years of Java iteration programming, it's still in my head :)